# Adjusting jQuery Click Handlers with ES6

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6

I've been writing my click handlers in jQuery the same way for the last 5 years.

```
$('.some-link').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

I love the new ES6 arrow syntax, but I can't figure out how to make jQuery work the same. For example, the below does not work as the above does:

```
$('.some-link').on('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Has anyone made the switch with their jQuery event handlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow functions are not just syntactic sugar to regular functions. There is one difference - they do not have their own context as regular functions, so they can not be used like this.

Under the hood, jquery binds the handler function with `event.target` (meaning `this` inside the handler will be `event.target`). But when you use arrow function, there is no function context created - more about this is described here on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this

You could do something like this:

```
$('.some-link').on('click', event => {
    $(event.target).addClass('active');
    return false; // this is same as calling `event.preventDefault();` in jquery
});
```